# WCF service for Silverlight application returns "NotFound"

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, web-config, subsonic

I have a WCF web service for a silverlight application that doesn't seem to want to work.

Pretty straight forward; when I debug the silverlight application and wcf at the same time, just after launching the WCF stops working and throws the following message:

> CommunicationException was unhandled by user code. 
>   The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

The WCF references another code library named DAL which uses SubSonic and stores a database file I'm working with.

Here is my WCF web.config file. There seems to be something wrong because there's no endpoints in it but I'm not entirely sure.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Database" connectionString='Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="[FILE LOCATION OF MDF FILE]";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True' providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You may be trying to serialize too much data.  Try increasing the [buffer size](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/40770.aspx)

Comment: I've tried increasing the maximum message size but it still throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In debugging this type of problem I typically use Fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to capture the actual response from WCF, which should give you much more detail about the problem since the NotFound message that SL gets hides the actual exception.

Comment: Just downloaded and installed that application and it says my web service is returning a 504 error to my application. Does this application detect what message the wcf threw to the client?

Comment: It manages to download the clientaccesspolicy.xml file i have in the root of my WCF, but the actual requests for data return with a 504 error.

Comment: How are you referencing the service from Silverlight?  Did _Add Service Reference_ find the appropriate contract?  If you right click on your .svc file in your web project, and set it as the startup page does it load appropriately?

Comment: Yeah the web service seems to be working okay. If I debug it by itself then it runs and i go to http://localhost:9141/Service1.svc it has the default page giving instructions on how to use the service.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be with the endpoints then, let's increase the timeout for the service call.  Add `<bindings><basicHttpBinding timeout="01:00" /></bindings>` to the system.serviceModel element in your web.config

Comment: It doesn't seem to like that, throws an error
`Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.`

Comment: try adding the following to the <system.serviceModel> tag: <services> 
    <service name ="Service1"> 
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:9141/Service1.svc" 
        binding="basicHttpBinding" /> 
    </service> 
</services>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7574/discussion-between-mlorbetske-and-tom-halley)

Comment: Hi sorry for delay i replied to your chat